# Using localStorage() in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, local-storage, angular-local-storage

I'm trying to use `localStorage` to save language preference in my app, but I can't seem to get it. Can anyone see why this isn't working and how I Can fix it?

**This is my code:**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title: string = 'app';
  currentLanguage = localStorage.getItem('language');
  currentPage: string;
  @ViewChild('bottom') bottomSection: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('top') topSection: ElementRef;


  constructor(private global: GlobalProvider, private translate: TranslateService, private scrollService: ScrollToService, private elementRef: ElementRef, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
    translate.setDefaultLang('en');
    this.changeLanguage('en');
  } 

  changeLanguage(language: string) {
    this.translate.use(language);
    this.currentLanguage = language;
    localStorage.setItem('language',language);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the declaration as,

```
 currentLanguage :string;
```

and then,

```
changeLanguage(language: string) {
    this.translate.use(language);
    this.currentLanguage = language;
    localStorage.setItem('language',language);
  }
```

Comment: I had that set up before and it still wasn't working

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage` isn't recognised by typescript, hence it would be throwing an error compile time. Declare ambient variable for `localStorage` so that typescript will analyse that `localStorage` variable has been defined and tooling system won't yell at it.

```
//write below line `AppComponent` class 
declare var localStorage: any;
```